Can I pass in Splendor if I have 10 gems?
In the game of Splendor, if I have 10 gems, can I pass by getting some gems and putting the same gems back to the bank?

As you pointed out, you can take 3 gems and return the same 3 at the end of your turn.  You can't pass your turn, since a turn is one of the four following actions:

Take 3 gem tokens of different colors.
Take 2 gem tokens of the same color.
This action is only possible if there are at least 4 tokens of the
chosen color left when the player takes them.
Reserve 1 development card and take 1 gold token (joker).
Purchase 1 face-up development card from the table or a previously reserved one.

Taking 3 gems and returning the same 3 is bad strategy. Splendor is fast paced (a game is usually around 20 rounds) and giving 5% up without any progress is giving advantage away.  If you want to keep a monopoly of gems to block other players, reserving a card would be your move.
